# Content section overlap footer

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a a page as following that works fine in big screens but in small screens the mainsection overlap the footer. How can I have the footer always at the bottom of the page. Also in small screens the location of the footer should be based on content of the page. In other words, if content is lengthy it should push footer to the bottom of the page. None of them should overlap the other.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/fju0vovy/)

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/4.2.1/bootstrap-social.css">

<style>
footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mainsection{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px black;
    background: white;
    display: flex;
}

.innersection {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 1900px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
}

.mainsection>img {
    height: 74px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.mainsection>span {
    width: calc(100% - 55px);
    margin-left: 2%;
}

@media ( min-width :599px) {
    .mainsection{
        width: 49%;
        margin: 0 2% 1em 0;
    }
}

@media ( min-width :599px) and (max-width:1024px) {
    .mainsection:nth-child(2n + 2) {
        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    }
}

@media ( min-width :1024px) {
    .mainsection{
        width: 24%;
        margin: 0 1.3333333333% 1em 0;
    }
    .mainsection:nth-child(4n + 4) {
        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    }
}
<!--
/
mainsectionisements
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
</div>
<ul class="innersection">
    <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>
        <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>
        <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>
        <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>
        <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>
        <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>
        <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>
        <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>

</ul>



    <footer>

<p>This is the footer.This is the footer.This is the footer.This is the footer.This is the footer.</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove - `position: absolute` for `footer`
2. create `wrapper` for page content to push down `footer`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 60px;
}

footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}

*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mainsection{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px black;
    background: white;
    display: flex;
}

.innersection {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 1900px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
}

.mainsection>img {
    height: 74px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.mainsection>span {
    width: calc(100% - 55px);
    margin-left: 2%;
}

@media ( min-width :599px) {
    .mainsection{
        width: 49%;
        margin: 0 2% 1em 0;
    }
}

@media ( min-width :599px) and (max-width:1024px) {
    .mainsection:nth-child(2n + 2) {
        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    }
}

@media ( min-width :1024px) {
    .mainsection{
        width: 24%;
        margin: 0 1.3333333333% 1em 0;
    }
    .mainsection:nth-child(4n + 4) {
        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
    <p>This is the container body</p>
</div>
<ul class="innersection">
    <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>
        <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>
        <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>
        <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>
        <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>
        <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>
        <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>
        <li class="mainsection"><span class="content"> <strong>This is Title</strong> <br /> <a href="tel:111111">111 111 111</a>
            <p>This is line 3</p>
            <p>This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.This is line 4.</p>
    </span></li>

</ul>
</div>


    <footer>

<p>This is the footer.This is the footer.This is the footer.This is the footer.This is the footer.</p>
</footer>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/muz9LL0r/)

Answer (score 3):

When we use absolute positioning we are taking the absolutely positioned element outside of the flow of the document where it will ignore the rest of the document's layout which is what is causing the overlap.

But - you want the footer to stick to the bottom even on a really large screen. So we use absolute positioning to make that happen but then add padding-top equal or greater to the height of the footer to prevent overlap when the user scrolls down.

```
footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    padding-top:60px;
}
```

I went so far as to test this on a big screen tv and it seems to produce the results you want. All code is the same as yours except the footer

Comment: If I remove that the footer moves to the middle of the page in large screens. Also in mobile screens the footer goes a bit above the bottom of the page.

Comment: Hmmm. I ran the code you posted on a local server and couldn't reproduce the results in your comment. Did you post all of the code or is there some scripting or additional css? Have you looked at the console and inspector? If you have inspected the footer is it getting all of it's styles from "inline" or are some coming from bootstrap? Also what browser are you using? You'll need a shim to do anything responsive in > IE9

Comment: The code in jsfiddle works; however, if you copy the whole code in html file you would be surprised that it does not work for big screens. (Footer goes to the middle of the page)

Comment: @jack - I did put the code in an HTML file and run it on a local server not just jsfiddle (as I mentioned above). I still can't reproduce your issue with the absolute positioning removed. I tested it on 3 different devices with no problem. Again, is that all of the code or is there scripting? What do you see in the console?

Comment: Strange, there is no other code, it is just a single page and the whole code is in the question. I do not see any thing in the console. In your case, is the footer at the bottom of the page in full size window?

Comment: OK. This one bothered me so I tried it on the biggest screen I could find. I have edited my answer and it looks like it works even on a very large tv. Let me know...

Comment: The issue with padding-top is that it just applies on the text of footer not its background-color, so if you set a background-color it would be apart from text. try adding background-color:green to style of footer please to see the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80609/discussion-between-helloworld-and-jack).

Comment: I Sorry I have not noticed you wrote something in the chat. Anyways, I used the code you suggested but footer is overlapping the content.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be simply the fact that you first say:

```
body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

and then a few lines later say:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

which overrides the margin-bottom and resets it to 0?

When I combined the body styles into one (having two sets of styles causes confusion, I fully recommend removing the second body {})

```
body {
    margin: 0 0 60px 0;
    padding: 0
}
```

it seemed to work pretty well.

I also experimented with margin-bottom and padding-bottom in both the html and body tags.  It really depends on what you are doing with borders and background, but another way to accomplish this is:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
html {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    ... other html styles
}
```

Both do the same thing, at least in my tests, but the body tag may be less confusing.  Hope this fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I replaced both body tags with body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} but still have the same issue.

Comment: Try body { margin: 0 0 60px 0; padding: 0 }

Answer (score 1):

remove `position: absolute;`

```
footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/fju0vovy/5/)

Comment: The code in jsfiddle works; however, if you copy the whole code in html file you would be surprised that it does not work for big screens. (Footer goes to the middle of the page)

Answer (score 1):

As with other answers, I took out the `position:absolute` and let it default to `position:static`

I then added style to the p child of the footer:

```
footer {
   bottom: 0;
   height: 60px;
   position: static;
   width: 100%;
}

footer p {position:absolute; bottom:0; height:0px;}
```

[Here's a link](https://jsfiddle.net/derrickmv/b10L4jow/).

Comment: The code in jsfiddle works; however, if you copy the whole code in html file you would be surprised that it does not work for big screens. (Footer goes to the middle of the page)

Comment: I see, where would you like the footer to end up at?

Comment: I need it to be at the bottom of the page all the time, the issue with my code is that the height of content does not have any influence on position of footer;therefore, in small screens the footer overlaps the content.

Comment: Interesting, on my big screen, the footer stays at the bottom of the page. [link here](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2d6r77l.jpg)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say if you add a background-color to the footer style you would see the text is apart from background. Current styling just affect the text. Please add background-color:green to the footer style to see.

Answer (score 1):

Removed bottom:0; and position:absolute in footer

```
footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks, the issue is that in small screens the footer overlaps the content.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
footer {
bottom: 0;
height: 60px;
position: absolute;
padding-top:50px;
width: 100%;
```

}

I Redmond to have Padding  in footer. Don't remove the position. It should work for you.

Comment: The issue with padding-top is that it just applies on the text of footer not its background-color, so if you set a background-color it would be apart from text. try adding background-color:green to style of footer please to see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
}
```

is absolutely essential as removing this would work too (in most cases).

My solution is to add padding-top on the footer.

```
footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

[This is what it looks like](https://jsfiddle.net/fju0vovy/6/)